# Android audio recorder with speech recognition

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, voice-recording

I'm looking for an audio recorder that can perform speech recognition while it is recording (but would also keep the audio recording) so that afterwards I could easily browse the recordings along with whatever text it managed to deduce from it.

Google Keep has a similar feature when recording notes, but whenever I stop talking for a couple of seconds it thinks I'm finished and stops recording.